# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'posts.post' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm very confused, i try to find what's wrong but i don't find it..

In my SQL Database i've 'posts' table created all my code are related with 'posts' table and not 'post' and im getting this error

Here is my Controller store method:

```
public function store(CreatePostRequest $request)
{
    //
    Post::create([
        'title'=>$request->title,
        'description'=>$request->descriptions,
        'is_active'=>isset($request->is_active)?1:0
    ]);
    falsh("Post Created Successfully");
    return redirect()->route('post.index');

}
```

And here is my model:

```
class posts extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable=['title','description','is_active'];
    protected $table = 'post';

}
```

Here is my artisan migrate table

```
class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title',100);
            $table->text('description');
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

How can i troubleshoot this?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are literally telling the Model to use the table named `post`: `protected $table = 'post';` ... and on a side note the Model should be named `Post`

Answer (score 0):

1. Model name is incorrect, not to mention you are calling `Post::create` and naming the model `posts`
2. Spot typos

Also a model with a lowercase letter is bad prac. `class Post`
below is the typo. naming it post while creating a table posts
To fix just remove the protected since its called posts regardless. rename your class to `class Post` done.

```
    protected $table = 'post';
```

```
Schema::create('posts', ....
```

try to spot typos

Answer (score 0):

create table for name (posts) not post.
name table is (example+s) = posts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).